# Bokeh TableData on_change selected event called twice

Tags: python, datatable, event-handling, bokeh

I have an Bokeh UI with a Select, a DataTable and a Button.

- Select allows to go directly to a given line in the DataTable
- Button allows to go to next line in DataTable
- DataTable allows direct single line selection (hence updates Select).

DataTable keeps tracking on selection change event through:

```
self.__table_data.on_change('selected',self.table_selection_change)
```

When button is clicked, I change the selected attribute of DataTable source with a new dict structure as seen [here](http://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/reference/models/sources.html#bokeh.models.sources.DataSource):

```
self.__table_data.selected = {'2d': {'indices': []}, '1d': {'indices': [my_new_index]}, '0d': {'indices': [], 'glyph': None}}
```

Problem is, when I did this update, my callback (table_selection_change) is called twice while I expect only one call.

Answer (score 1):

Problem is that whole dict should not be updated. Only relevant keys must be updated.

Replacing

```
self.__table_data.selected = {'2d': {'indices': []}, '1d': {'indices': [my_new_index]}, '0d': {'indices': [], 'glyph': None}}
```

by

```
self.__table_data.selected['1d'] = {'indices':[my_new_index]}
```

solves the problem.